# Strategies To Reduce Compressed File Lookup Time With Pixz?

Tags: compression, tar

I have a PIXZ-compressed (level `-9`) tarball containing around 4000 files (ordered, like pages in a book): compressed size is ~670M.  Currently I am programmatically accessing these files using the standard way, i.e.

`pixz -x <compressed_file_name> < tarball.tpxz | tar x -O`

Based on metrics using `time`, extraction of the file takes on average 1.7 seconds.  Since this is part of a programmatic process, I wanted to get that time down if possible, so I thought of splitting the `tpxz` archive into three smaller ~200M segments (each containing ~1000 files), with the expectation that `pixz -x` would run significantly faster against any one of these three segments than it does against the ~600M original. (I can predict which of the three segments contains a file required for the process.)

However to my surprise, the time metrics against the 200M segments are identical to those for the original: lookup/decompression still runs 1.7 seconds on average.  As this is at odds both with intuition and with results in an extremal case - lookup/decompression against a `-9`-compressed tarball containing a single file completes in a trivial amount of time - I am curious why my segmentation strategy failed, and whether there are any other strategies folks can recommend to improve the performance of `pixz` lookups against largish files: 1.7 seconds is certainly acceptable, particularly given what you save in storage costs, but a faster time would be nice.

If there's some tarball size and/or archive file number threshold past which completion time remains roughly constant for `pixz` lookup/decompression jobs, it would be both interesting and useful to know that, so thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Of course the times are the same. Decompression is mainly a CPU job and that is the same regardless whether the archive has 3 entries or 3000 entries. There may be just a very small difference in disk time if you have an old fashioned spinning disk.

Comment: Then why the large difference in the extremal case? Or in a subsequent test with 40-file segments, lookup times decrease to .5 second

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of pixz. Pixz already uses internal blocking for looking up files, that's why using "pixz -x file < my.tpxz" tends to be faster than just "tar -xJf my.tpxz file".

When you're using high compression, you block sizes end up huge, which makes extraction of a single file slower than lower compression settings. You can use "xz -lv" on your .tpxz file to see what sizes the blocks are.